# Create "[FOLLOW]" relation between multiple :Users who "[:RATED]" arbitrary :Movies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Graph that I want create between already existing nodes

[image]

I want to create FOLLOW relationship between multiple users in my database who have rated any movie. I have no idea how to do this with a single and simple query. I tried the following query and it simply failed with some JAVA heap space error.

```
MATCH (m1:Movie)<-[r1:RATED]-(elisha:User), (m2:Movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(garfield:User),(m3:Movie)<-[r3:RATED]-(hermann:User),(m4:Movie)<-[r4:RATED]-(lester:User),
(m5:Movie)<-[r5:RATED]-(casper:User),(m6:Movie)<-[r6:RATED]-(lester:User),
(m7:Movie)<-[r7:RATED]-(alaa:User),(m8:Movie)<-[r8:RATED]-(jake:User),
(m9:Movie)<-[r9:RATED]-(odie:User),(m10:Movie)<-[r10:RATED]-(pink:User)
CREATE (elisha)-[:FOLLOW]->(garfield),
(garfield)-[:FOLLOW]->(hermann),
(garfield)-[:FOLLOW]->(lester),
(lester)-[:FOLLOW]->(elisha),
(casper)-[:FOLLOW]->(pink),
(alaa)-[:FOLLOW]->(jake),
(jake)-[:FOLLOW]->(garfield),
(jake)-[:FOLLOW]->(odie)
```

I am new to Neo4j and Cypher query language so kindly help me understand this.

Comment: You're going to need to better explain the criteria for what determines which users will follow who. None of the movies are in common, each one is rated only once, so there's nothing to group on except that they have all rated any movie. But there's nothing to explain what logic to use to connect them the way you did. Not all of the users are interconnected (there are 6 other users Casper isn't following, for example), so you've got to explain to us what logic we're supposed to use to get your desired graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let me walk you through creating one relationship, you can mimic it for the rest. Assuming that your nodes with the label User have a name parameter.

```
MATCH (m1:Movie)<-[r1:RATED]-(e:User {name: 'elisha'})
WITH m1,e
MATCH (m3:Movie)<-[r3:RATED]-(g:User {name: 'garfield'})
WITH m3, g
.
.
CREATE (e)-[:FOLLOW]->(g)
CREATE (e)-[:FOLLOW]->(h)
```

Comment: That works fine for just one node. When I try to MATCH multiple nodes and then create Multiple "FOLLOW" relations using same method, it says "no changes made". Have a look at my query :

'MATCH (m1:Movie)<-[r1:RATED]-(e:User {username: 'Elisha'}), (m2:Movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(g:User {username: 'Garfield'}),(m3:Movie)<-[r3:RATED]-(h:User {username: 'Hermann'}),(m4:Movie)<-[r4:RATED]-(l:User {username: 'Lester'}),(m5:Movie)<-[r5:RATED]-(c:User {username: 'Casper'}), (m6:Movie)'

'CREATE (e)-[:FOLLOW]->(g),(g)-[:FOLLOW]->(h),(g)-[:FOLLOW]->(l),(c)-[:FOLLOW]->(a),(c)-[:FOLLOW]->(p)'

Comment: That works totally fine and I understand that. But it uses CREATE two times and I prefer to do both creations with a single CREATE.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve all these with a single MATCH and single CREATE?